# Adding ffmpeg as environment variable

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, environment-variables

I've been trying to follow step two of the dependence guide of Microsofts Project Malmo.

https://github.com/Microsoft/malmo/blob/master/doc/install_windows.md

I need to create the environment variable for ffmpeg. I have installed ffmpeg at C:\ffmpeg so that it's bin is at C:\ffmpeg\bin. I have tried the following

**Through command prompt**

```
set ffmpeg=C:\ffmpeg\bin
```

**Through GUI menu**

```
My Computer
Environment variables
Add
Name ffmpeg
Value C:\ffmpeg\bin
```

Neither has worked. I should be able to type ffmpeg and see it's recognized, but I'm currently still getting the "Not recognized" error.

** Edit: ** [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them) seems to me to be recommending the steps I've already taken. If I have made a mistake in my steps, please point it out.

Comment: From the link you posted "Add C:\ffmpeg\bin to your **PATH**"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

Comment: @DavidPostill See my edit. I followed the steps of that question but I'm still having difficulties.

Comment: You have added a new environment variable called `ffmpeg`. You are supposed to add `C:\ffmpeg\bin` to the existing `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: [How to Edit Your System PATH for Easy Command Line Access in Windows](http://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/)

Comment: @DavidPostill Thank you, that is probably part of the misunderstanding, but I'm still getting "Not recognised" error. I added it for user and system environment variables, no luck.

Comment: Please [edit] and add the output from running `path` in a `cmd` shell.

Comment: It didn't have the ffmpeg variable, but after closing and reopening command prompt, ffmpeg is now included and the command works as expected. Thanks for your help. Post the bit on editing path instead of adding new and I will happily accept.

Comment: Answer added :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### I should be able to type `ffmpeg` and see it's recognized

> but I'm currently still getting the "Not recognized" error.

You have added a **new** environment variable called `ffmpeg`.

You are supposed to add `C:\ffmpeg\bin` to the **existing** `PATH` environment variable.

See [How to Edit Your System PATH for Easy Command Line Access in Windows](http://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/) or [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them) for instructions.

Note:

- If you change the path using the Control panel GUI you need to close and restart any `cmd` shells to see the change.

Answer (score 0):

Copy ffmpeg.exe to C:\Windows\System32

No need to mess with any other variables. However, this may be considered a security issue.